# making ActionBar icon dynamically visible/invisible

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, broadcastreceiver

My MainActivity calls an AsyncTask to do some network I/O.  When the AsyncTask begins, I would  like to 'light up' an icon in the ActionBar.  When the AsyncTask completes, I would like to make that ActionBar icon invisible, i.e. upon AsyncTask completion, not via a button click.

At this point I can successfully light up the ActionBar icon upon AsyncTask start.  At the completion of AsyncTask, I send another broadcast back to MainActivity to indicate that AsyncTask is completed.  I need to be able to use this broadcast to make the ActionBar icon invisible.  I am attempting to used InvalidateMenuOptions() to force onPrepareMenuOptions to  recreate and make the ActionBar icon invisible, but it is not working. Here is my attempt so far - all code is excerpted from my MainActivity class

excerpt from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static boolean dataXferRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // broadcast receiver to determine if BasestationTransfer is active
        basestationBroadcastReceiver = new BasestationBroadcastReceiver();
        basestationIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("XFER_RUNNING_ACTION");

        boolean hasWifi = CWICUtil.getNetworkState(this);
        if(hasWifi) {
            if(dataXferRunning == false) {
                containerCount = 0;
                DBAdapter dbAdapter = CWICApplication.dbAdapter();
                try {
                    containerCount = (int)dbAdapter.getUnsentContainersCount();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getUnsentContainersCount() failed: " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(containerCount > 0) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    startTransfer();  //AsyncTask
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my BroadcastReciever:

```
public static class BasestationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.getAction();
        boolean isRunning = intent.getBooleanExtra("XFER_RUNNING", false);
        if(isRunning) {
            dataXferRunning = true;
        } else {
            dataXferRunning = false;
        }
    }
};
```

my onPrepareOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareMenuOptions(Menu menu) {
    if(dataXferRunning) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_socketServiceConnected).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_socketServiceConnected).setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

So to summarize - I'm successfully receiving broadcasts from my AsyncTask with correct values.  I have seen much code that does this with a buttonClick, however my issue is dynamically making my ActionBar icon invisible upon completion of AsyncTask.  Also - this is my first time posting, let me know if I can clarify any issues plus thanks to this community because you have been getting me out of jams for months now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, you can hold on to a reference of your `Menu` object (via a class variable, or some other mechanism of your choice), like this:

```
Menu menu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
  getSupportMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.my_menu, menu );
  this.menu = menu;     

  return true;
}
```

Then, when you want to dynamically adjust the menu item's visibility, you can reuse that menu object reference to call `menu.findItem(R.id.myId)` to get your individual menu items and adjust their properties dynamically however you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I ended up doing

    `menu.findItem(R.id.xxx).setVisible(true);`

in onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and  

    `menu.findItem(R.id.xxx).setVisible(false);`

in the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Yes, the problem i had seems that the onCreateOptionsMenu was called after the broadcastregister so the true option would never activate for me for some reason....